# find pattern and remove few character only

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I was trying to search for a pattern in string using javascript methods available inside Nodejs and replace few characters with some other character in the same found pattern.

For example:
I am searching for "*,*"
Any thing enclosed inside double quotes and has comma in between
I need to remove double quotes and comma in between.

The scenario is like, I can have multiple strings also separated by comma
for example: 123,234,**"1,234.50"**,345,456

I need to perform this operation only on those pattern which is inside double quotes. So after conversion, it has to be like  123,234,**1234.50**,345,456

How can I do that in a shot for a long text?

Comment: [`str.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, (_, $1) => $1.replace(/,/g, ''))`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wewxagb0/)

Comment: Welcome. Before you ask next question see [ask] and [mcve]. Always add your attempts to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` with captured group regex

```js
document.write(
  // get the values withing `""`
  '123,234,"1,234.50",345,456'.replace(/,"(.+?)",/g, function(m, m1) {
    // replace the `,` within the `""` and update
    return ',' + m1.replace(/,/g, '') + ',';
  })
)
```

with ES6 arrow function

```js
document.write(
  '123,234,"1,234.50",345,456'.replace(/,"(.+?)",/g, (m, m1) => ',' + m1.replace(/,/g, '') + ',')
)
```